# C++ Unresolved overloaded function type

Tags: c++, typedef, overloading

I am running into issue with the typedef/call back function.

```
typedef void (*timer_cb_fn_t)(void); //defined in timer.h
```

Here is the definition of timer_start function defined in timer.cpp

```
unsigned int TimClass:: timer_start(unsigned int interval, timer_cb_fn_t cb)
{
 //do stuff 
}
```

dpl.h includes timer.h

I am trying to invoke the timer function from dpl.cpp file
where call back function is defined as

```
 void Dpl::receive_timeout(void)
    {
        receive_state = STATE_IDLE;
    }
```

I am invoking the function timer start with the following call.

```
unsigned int receive_timer = timer_start(TIMER_FRAME_TIME_MS, receive_timeout);
```

The g++ compiler throws the following errors.

```
./src/dpl/dpl.cc:138:107: error: no matching function for call to ‘TimClass::timer_start(unsigned int, <unresolved overloaded function type>)’
../dpl.cc:138:107: note: candidate is:
../timer.h:256:16: note: unsigned int TimClass::timer_start(unsigned int, timer_cb_fn_t)
../timer.h:256:16: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘timer_cb_fn_t {aka void (*)()}’
make: *** [build/dpl.o] Error 1
```

Could you please explain how to address this?

Comment: please always post a [mcve]

Comment: Not an answer, so I'm posting as a comment: you may not want to use function pointers in C++. Though they're still useful in specific circumstances, I think templates/functors and `std::function` between them cover the majority of use cases better.

Comment: I don't know the C+++ language (as specified in title), probably next generation of C++? :)

Answer (score 3):

The type of `Dpl::receive_timeout` is `void (Dpl::*)(void)` and it takes an implicit `this` parameter. Make your function static (I don't think you can do this since you seem to be using non-static class members) or change your timer definition to accept any functor and pass a lambda/`std::function<void(void)>`.

static callback:

```
// function declaration
class Dpl{
    // ...
    static receive_timeout(void);
    // ...
};

// function definition
void Dpl::receive_timeout(void)
{
    receive_state = STATE_IDLE;
}
```

lambda:

```
template<typename T>
unsigned int TimClass:: timer_start(unsigned int interval, T&& callback)
{
//do stuff 
}
```

`std::function`: (note: uses type erasure, which is more costly at the runtime)

```
unsigned int TimClass:: timer_start(unsigned int interval, std::function<void(void)> const& callback)
{
//do stuff 
}
```

By the way, if you want to take address of a member function, you need to use the qualified name and `operator&`:

```
&Dpl::receive_timeout
```

Comment: If the function is templated and accepts any functor, there's no reason to construct an `std::function`, you would just pass the lambda directly. More common is the opposite, for the function to accept an `std::function`, and to pass a lambda or a function into it; typically you do this when you want to avoid templating and/or need type erasure.

Comment: I wanted to say that those are two popular alternatives for the interface. I'll clarify.

Comment: Technically speaking, this must be a free function. Static methods are allowed to have different call convention. So this is UB. But I know no platform where calling conventions will be different and static function is better for code readability.

Comment: @krzaq. Thanks for chiming in. I tried the first solution by using the same syntax as you suggested. It would still throw erros

Comment: Well, I cleared the example up. If you can avoid using class instance variables it'll work for you. otherwise it will not.

Comment: I am using class variables inside the call back function hence the solution with static keyword won't work. I attempted the solution with lambda but don't know if I am putting the correct syntax. It gives the following errors if I use the way you have typed in.

Comment: timer.cpp                                                                                template <typename T>
unsigned int TimClass:: timer_start(unsigned int interval, T&& cb)   ../dpl.cpp:210:93: error: no matching function for call to ‘TimClass:timer_start(int, <unresolved overloaded function type>)’
../dpl.cc:210:93: note: candidate is:
../timer.h:258:16: note: unsigned int TimClass::timer_start(unsigned int, T&&) [with T = void (Dpl::*)()]
../timer.h258:16: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘void (Dpl::*&&)()